# Sort of native Windows apps with web languages?

Tags: windows, web-applications, native, appcelerator

So I was searching the Interweb for like 1h now and couldn't find any good intel so I'm asking here! :-)

I'm looking for solutions like [Appcelerator](http://www.appcelerator.com/) (for mobile platforms) or Adobe Air for making real native Windows apps just with my web-coding skills.

What do I mean by that?
Building a whole "sort of native" App for Windows 7 (8) only with HTML(5), CSS(3), JS, JQuery + any other JS lib.

Of course I would prefer something where the user in the end doesn't have to install a ton of runtimes.

Any ideas?

best regards
Patrick

Comment: Uhm, I'm afraid there is no such thing really. Also, the use of "native" is a bit ambiguous, but I presume you refer to native in the sense of pure Win32 subsystem versus JITed CIL? ...

Comment: Yep you are right! native is a bit the wrong word for what I am looking for.

Comment: XAML and friends get pretty close to what you need, but the question is what exactly those "web-coding skills" of yours are. You should probably amend your question accordingly ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can develop Windows Store Apps for Windows 8 using HTML, CSS, and JavaScript. That includes jQuery and all the other shiny JavaScript libraries out there.

Comment: I know! :) but imho Win8 is crap! haha ... so I would rly like to develop apps for Win7!